# Fourier Transform of a function that is zero for $x<0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I have this function
$$
f(x)=xH(x)\ln{(x)}e^{-x},
$$
of which I need the Fourier transform, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. Maple tells me the Fourier transform is
$$
{\frac { \left({\omega}+i \right)^2 \left(\ln  {\left(\sqrt{
\omega^2+1}\right)} + i \arctan \left( \omega \right) + \gamma-1 \right) }{ \left( {\omega}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}
,
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

I have computed it several different ways through Maple and I believe it is the right formula. I tried to do it analytically but I never quite got there. If someone would know the steps to get there, I would really appreciate it.

I need this result because I need to check in which fractional Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ does $f$ belong to.

Comment: Are you sure that is $e^x$ and not $e^{-x}$?  Developing a Fourier Transform with the exponential with positive, increasing argument in there would be quite a feat.

Comment: @Andy Walls Yes, $e^{-x}$. Thank you.

Comment: To compute FT i.e. $\int_{\mathbb R^+} x^{s-1} e^{-(1+i w x)} \log(x) dx$, one may simply differentiate the Gamma expression $\int_{\mathbb R^+} x^{s-1} e^{-(1+i w x)} dx$ w.r.t $s$ once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform of a function $f$ is traditionally denoted ${\displaystyle {\hat {f}}}$, by adding a circumflex to the symbol of the function. There are several common conventions for defining the Fourier transform of an integrable function ${\displaystyle f:\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {C} }$. [One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition) of them is:

$$\hat{f}\left(\xi\right):=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\exp\left(-2\pi x\xi i\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

for any real number $\xi$ with $i^2=-1$.

Using your function, we can notice that:

$$\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)=\int_0^\infty x\ln\left(x\right)\exp\left(-x\right)\exp\left(-2\pi x\xi i\right)\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Let's define a second integral:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right):=\int_0^\infty x\ln\left(x\right)\exp\left(-\text{s}x\right)\exp\left(\text{n}x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

Using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition), we can write:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_x\left[x\ln\left(x\right)\exp\left(\text{n}x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag4$$

Using the frequency-domain derivative and frequency shifting [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform, we can write:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}-\text{n}\right)}\right\}\tag5$$

Using [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of selected Laplace transforms, we can write:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\frac{\ln\left(\text{s}-\text{n}\right)+\gamma}{\text{n}-\text{s}}\right\}=\frac{1-\gamma-\ln\left(\text{s}-\text{n}\right)}{\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)^2}\tag6$$

Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Going back to $(2)$ we can see that:

$$\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)=\int_0^\infty x\ln\left(x\right)\exp\left(-x\right)\exp\left(-2\pi x\xi i\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{1-\gamma-\ln\left(1-\left(-2\pi\xi i\right)\right)}{\left(\left(-2\pi\xi i\right)-1\right)^2}=$$
$$\frac{1-\gamma-\ln\left(1+2\pi\xi i\right)}{\left(\left(-2\pi\xi i\right)-1\right)^2}=\frac{1-\gamma-\ln\left(1+2\pi\xi i\right)}{\left(1+2\pi\xi i\right)^2}\tag7$$

Comment: Given that Maple defines the Fourier transform as $\hat{f}\left(\omega \right):=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\exp\left(-\omega x i\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1,$  your last expression becomes $$\frac{1-\gamma-\ln\left(1-\omega i\right)}{\left(1+\omega i\right)^2}$$.

Comment: @Stephane that is true.

Comment: @Stephane true! You're welcome.

Comment: Actually, there should be a "+" in front of the $2\pi$ on the top of the fraction in (7) so I need a "$\ln{(1+\omega i)}$" in my first comment. So, to complete the response: $$\frac{1-\gamma-\ln{(1+\omega i)}}{(1+\omega i)^2}=\frac{(\omega+i)^2}{(1+\omega^2)^2}(\ln{(1+\omega i)}+\gamma-1).$$ Then, because $$1+\omega i=\sqrt{1+\omega^2}\left(\frac{i-\omega}{i+\omega}\right)^{1/2}$$ we have that $$\ln{(1+\omega i)}=\ln{(\sqrt{1+\omega^2})}+i\frac{1}{2i}\ln{\left(\frac{i-\omega}{i+\omega}\right)}=\ln{(\sqrt{1+\omega^2})}+i\arctan{(\omega)}.$$ This completes the argument.

Comment: @Stephane I fixed it and you're right.